# console.log not displaying anything in the terminal (node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, node-modules, console.log

im still very new to nodeJS and i have run into a problem.

whenever i try to log something from my aplication to the terminal using " node [application name]" nothing happen please help if you can, thank you!

**please keep in mind that it was working before so i broke it**

i have already tried to use another terminal (bash) and nothing happend; but for some reason when i use nodemon it works im very confused so any thing will be helpful

**CODE:**

```js
console.log('hello world...');
```

**TERMINAL:**

```
PS C:\Users\nsc\Desktop\npm> node app

PS C:\Users\nsc\Desktop\npm>
```

Comment: hey ArabDROPS! Welcome! is there any more information you can share? maybe explain what you did that broke the normal behavior? it's hard to help you fix this with only the information you provided. thanks!

Comment: Seems odd.  I can see your using powershell, does it do the same using standard cmd shell?.   If so it's maybe some funky powershell settings rather than node..

Comment: Did you save your file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turned out that the problem was  i did not save the file, if your having the same issue please try to save before runing.

Answer (score -1):

run the file with .js extensions your run only with filename `node app`

try to run `node app.js`

Comment: Extension is not important if you run it directly with node. In fact it is standard on Linux to not give your executable scripts any extensions so your script will look like a regular app (regular apps on Linux don't have any extensions unlike Windows with .exe or MacOS with .app). Node supports scripts without extensions